# How to clear image input in each loop of jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to clear the image which is invalid image format. I've tried multiple times but didn't work. How can I achieve it. Using jQuery 3.6.0

```
$(':file').change(function(){
        var fileArray = this.files;
        var validImageTypes = ["image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/png"];
        $.each(fileArray,function(i,v){
          type = v.type;
          if ($.inArray(type, validImageTypes) < 0) {
            alert('Only jpg, jpeg and png is allowed.');
            // here i want to clear the image which is selected
            };
        })
        });
```

I've tried using `$(this).val("")` but not working. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` points the function called in each.

Use an arrow function to automatically bind to the parent context, (the file element).

```
$(':file').change(function() {
var fileArray = this.files;
var validImageTypes = ["image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/png"];
$.each(fileArray, (i, v) => {
    type = v.type;
    if ($.inArray(type, validImageTypes) < 0) {
        alert('Only jpg, jpeg and png is allowed.');
        // here i want to clear the image which is selected
        $(this).val(""); 
    };
})});
```